# rate of convergence of sample mean

Tags: probability, distributions

Law of large number ensures the convergence of sample mean to population mean. But it does not tell about the rate of convergence. Now CLT tells about the rate of convergence. Then what is the necessity of Berry-Essen theorem which also gives us the rate of convergence?

Comment: The question would be more useful to others if you could include a quick reminder of the three results.

Comment: CLT gives rate of convergence to the mean, Berry-Esseen theorem gives something about rate of convergence to the limiting normal distribution in CLT.

Comment: I cannot understand. Why CLT gives rate of convergence to the mean? It deals with asymptotic distribution of sample mean. And that is normal distribution. And Berry Essen theorem deals with the absolution difference of the distribution function of the same variable with limiting normal distribution. So both are dealing with the same thing with different approach.

Comment: I think if you were to try to explain the precise senses in which the CLT and the Barry-Esseen Theorems give "rates of convergence," you would have the answer to your question.